# Autojit - how to increase performance for rotating

Tags: python, anaconda, numba, numba-pro

I have the following code:

```
def rotation_cpu(img, theta, dst):
    cosTheta = np.cos(theta)
    sinTheta = np.sin(theta)
    for i in range(512):
        for j in range(512):
            xpos = cosTheta * i - sinTheta * j
            ypos = sinTheta * i + cosTheta * j
            dst[xpos + 725/2, ypos ] = img[i,j]
```

I'm testing it, and I get `1.7300620079`seconds. But, when I use the `@autojit` decorator it get worse.

```
from numbapro import autojit

@autojit
def rotation_cpu(img, theta, dst):
    cosTheta = np.cos(theta)
    sinTheta = np.sin(theta)
    for i in range(512):
        for j in range(512):
            xpos = cosTheta * i - sinTheta * j
            ypos = sinTheta * i + cosTheta * j
            dst[xpos + 725/2, ypos ] = img[i,j]
```

with `1.92721390724` seconds. Should I change something to get better performances?

The code for testing is:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from scipy.misc import imread

img = imread("pic.jpg") # it is a 512x512 pic.
theta = 45
ts = timer()
dst = np.zeros((725, 725)) # new boundaries
rotation_cpu(img, theta * np.pi / 180, dst)
te = timer()

print te - ts
```